# Dell 1320c - Catalina 10.15 Mac Pro - will print but only from single feed - How to fix?

Tags: mac, catalina, printing

the link to the recommended driver worked - but only so far as I can insert a single page versus auto feeding from Tray one. Anyone have any ideas how to change this ? the operator panel is not so helpful and the DELL printer web page not accessible as far as I can see. I can print other printer setting from that tray bu holding down the continue button so nothing wrong mechanically. thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I started playing with the tray settings. When I switched to 250+500 sheets - everything started working ok. 
Also, if you are in the Word, use this setting - you can choose them by selecting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following the recipe given by Alex S.:

1. yes, one can select Tray 1 in Word and it prints from the tray just fine,
2. then you define a new preset with its own name, like "Tray 1 feed",
3. this preset is system-wide, and as such can be selected for printing in e.g. Acrobat Reader DC by clicking the "Printer..." button